# Имя Encoding не существует в данном контексте

Tags: c#

При дебаге в консоле отображаются русские символы как - "?".
Решил воткнуть в код строку - `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`
Но теперь Visual Studio ругается, ссылаясь на то что чего-то там где-то там не существует. Помогите пожалуйста, великие гуру шарпа)

p.s. У меня Mac

```
using System;

namespace PlsRunPls
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("Что-нибудь"); // :)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Про  `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` узнал на стаке)
Может есть какая-нибудь замена ему? Что-бы на любых ПК и ОС отображались русские символы а не "??"

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`?

Comment: @tym32167 Ахаха. работает) Спасибо великий человек)

Comment: Вы серьезно? Что за чушь я тут сейчас увидел? Ну ей богу, вам даже студия должна подсказывать о доступном `namespace`, который надо указать в `using` или при вызове. Это же самая основа программирования на C#... Позор!

Comment: Автору рекомендуется прочитать [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.25.php)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Плохой комментарий, непрофессиональный. Вместо того чтобы рефлексировать, лучше бы дали автору что почитать. Впрочем, я это уже сделал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Позор ты. Я написал что у меня мак, в макОС нет этого. Внимательнее читай

Comment: @aepot Спасибо)

Comment: @x11repo Бред говорите, например вот первый скрин [из интернета](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oKLsFRe1uXw/maxresdefault.jpg). А вот вам [видео](https://youtu.be/oKLsFRe1uXw?t=587) (9:47 если что). Хорошо, даже если нет, вы сами пробовали найти ответ? Пишем в любом поисковике `c# Encoding`, находим [официальную документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding) и видим `Пространство имен:
System.Text`. Сейчас уж извините, вы просто написали вопрос, даже не подумав что и как сами, а это для меня извините, лично противно. Я надеюсь в будущем вы больше начнете думать сами.

Comment: @aepot Давайте на чистоту, какую пользу несет данный вопрос для базы вопросов SO? Лично я против подобного здесь, это мусор, обычный мусор, который произошел из за того, что человеку лень было уделить пару минут своего времени для решения задачи и он решил потратить время других. Это вопрос из разрядка "Как кушать кашу?". Так простите, какой смысл мне тратить свое время на то, что бы помогать человеку, который не смог уделить время для самого себя? Я даже уверен, что на SO есть дубликаты этого вопроса. Короче, я думаю дальше бессмысленно это обсуждать, у каждого свое видение ситуации.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ничего личного, вы мне не раз помогли здесь своими ответами, и я вам благодарен, но я бы предложил подобное оставить модераторам и изначально проходить мимо. А если совсем невмоготу, можно нажать на флажок.

Comment: @aepot Хах, модераторы вон походу ради репутации ответы дают на вопросы, где не надо думать, а сообщество до сих пор не может понят какие вопросы нужны на ruSO, а какие нет. О чем вы говорите) Я такое написал по одной причине - показать автору на его не хотение разобраться в ситуации, чтоб дальше он понимал "ага, стоит сначала попробовать решить задачу самому, а не просить помощи у прохожих". Надеюсь, что он пойдем тот факт, что некоторым такое отношение не нравиться и в дальнейшем больше будет уважать людей за той стороной монитора. Вы если хотите продолжить обсуждение - создавайте чат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если тебе не нравятся подобные вопросы, то зачем ты на них отвечаешь? Зачем ты вообще сидишь на stack?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ты противоречишь сам себе, ты вместо того что-бы пройти мимо, начала поносить своими возмущениями.  Не хочешь тратить своё время? Проходи мимо, не высерай такой бред, все когда-то были новичками.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я изначально пытался сам решить эту проблему, я учу C# втрой день! В гугле я не нашел ответ, на SO был, но он мне тоже не помог, поэтому я сам написал тему на SO.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если не хотите тратить своё время, то уходите с SO

Comment: @x11repo Не поверите, вы единственный с таким примитивным вопросом по метке C# за долгое время моего нахождения тут. Повторюсь, это равноценно "Как скушать кашу?", достаточно подумать чуть чуть и задача решиться. Если вы  и дальше будете по каждому пустяку задавать подобные вопросы, то вряд-ли научитесь чему либо годному. Я не бомблю, не помнось, мне плевать на вас и на всю это ситуацию, лишь противно и обидно за мое любимое сообщество, не более... Вам желаю всего наилучшего в изучение языка, удачи! (дальнейшее обсуждение только в чате если хотите).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Для вас это "Как скушать кашу", а для меня это "Как решить задачу по квантовой физике на арабском языке". Я повторюсь, в шарпе я 2 дня, я подумал,  но решить проблему не смог, на mac `using System.Text;` не импортируется

Answer (score 1):

Добавь к юсингам

```
using System.Text;
```

PS: Только вообще-то консоли кодировку задавать не надо - она и так хорошо работает - тут же не джава и не плюсы.

Comment: без кодировки, все буквы кроме Английских, у меня отображались как "?".
`using System.Text;` в VS на mac не импортируется должным образом

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

> ```
> Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
> ```

Вставляем

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```